# Deserializing XML to List of C# objects in for loop too slow

Tags: c#, xml, performance, serialization, xmlserializer

I have a C# file which was auto generated by using the wsdl.exe utility.
This file contains the "MyObject" class used in the code example below.
I am now trying to Deserialize the raw response of the webservice to the object model manually.

The XML structure looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns2:myResponse xmlns:ns2="http://myurl.com">
            <return>...</return>
            <return>...</return>
            <return>...</return>
            ...
        </ns2:myResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The following code works for deserializing the "return" elements to "MyObject":

```
var file = @"C:\Data\example_response.xml";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var myNamespace = "http://myurl.com";
var results = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("myResponse", myNamespace)).Elements();
var myObjects = new List<MyObject>();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xRoot.ElementName = "return";
    xRoot.IsNullable = true;

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyObject), xRoot);
    var output = (MyObject)serializer.Deserialize(result.CreateReader());

    myObjects.Add(myObject);
}
```

The problem is the above code is terribly slow. It takes 6 secondes to iterate over 400 "return" elements.
It would probably be advised to run the XmlSerializer Deserialize method outside of the foreach-loop, but I am unable to get this working with the code below:

```
var file = @"C:\Data\example_response.xml";
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(file);
var myNamespace = "http://myurl.com";
var results = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("myResponse", myNamespace)).ElementAt(0).ToString();

XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
xRoot.Namespace = myNamespace;
xRoot.ElementName = "myResponse";
xRoot.IsNullable = true;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MyObject>), xRoot);
var output = (List<MyObject>)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(results));
```

The code above is resulting into an empty list (probably because the XmlSerializer does not recognize the "return" element to be a "MyObject", but I don't want to make changes to the generated C# file.

I feel like there's a terribly easy solution for my problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Create the serializer outside the loop. Or create a wrapper class that contains the `myResponse` property and deserialize into that.

Comment: You need a **single** xml-root-tag, not a list of them. Otherwise your xml is not even well-formed. Thus create a class whose only member is a `List<MyObject>` and deserialize that instead. In your case I suppose you want to deserialize the `Envelope `-object. You can´t deserialize only a part of an xml-document.

Comment: I managed to solve it by using a wrapper class: [XmlRoot(ElementName="myResponse", Namespace="http://myurl.com")]
public class MyObject{
 [XmlElement(ElementName="return", Form=XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
 public List<obj> objs{get;set;}
}